# How to prove that $4^n>n^2$ using induction...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

today I've encountered a question like the following;
$$\text{Prove that }4^n>n^2\text{ using induction.}$$ 
**My Attempts:**

I have realised that this works for $P(1)$, my next attempt was $p(n)\implies p(n+1)$....(1)

I have tried to multiply both sides with a $4$ which gave $4^{n+1}>4n^2$ I have tried to turn it out like $4>1^2$ and that gave me $4^{n+1}>n^2\cdot1^2$.....(2)

After that pointless attempt I've added $2n+1$ to both sides but I couldn't figure out still what $2n$ goes to in the left side...(3)

What are your suggestions?

With the real question being the first one, is there any other way to prove this numerically? (Perhaps in a more entertaining way?:))

Comment: Prove $2^n>n$. when $2^k>k$ then $2^{k+1}>2k>k+1$.

Comment: Okay. It is true for $P(1)$ and $P(n+1): 2^n\cdot2>2n$. How can I get rid of the $2$ at the right side? (Thanks for the advice by the way:))

Comment: I see your edit. Thank you:)

Comment: $$\begin{align} 4^n &> n^2 \\ \iff 2^{2\times n} &> n^{2\times 1} \\ \iff 2^n &> n \\ \iff 2^n &> \log_2 k \end{align}$$ for which $k = 2^n$, which is true. The reason this is a comment is because I didn't prove this using induction

Comment: You could've put this as an answer too, another part of my question was without induction. Thank you:)

Comment: In fact, for all $\ell \in \mathbb{N}, \ 4\ell < 2^{\ell}$

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}  \leqslant 4$$ for $n \geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerically is not a proof.

Induction works in this way

1. It is true for $n=1$
2. Suppose that is is true for $n>1$, prove it for $n+1$
3. It is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

proof

1. actually $4^1> 1^2$
2. (I.H.) if $4^n>n^2$ for $n>1$ consider that $4^{n+1}=4\cdot 4^n$. Now use the Inductive Hypothesis (I.H.)

$4\cdot 4^n > 4\cdot n^2 =2^2 \cdot n^2=(2n)^2>(n+1)^2$ as $n>1$

proved, so

3. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $4^n>n^2$

*QED*
$$
.
$$

To say the truth $4^n > n^{1000}$ for $n>6312$

Indeed induction can start from any $n$, but this is another story

Comment: Technically your proof is invalid because $(2n)^2 > (n+1)^2$ fails for $n = 1$. You needed to separate $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ into separate cases.

Comment: @orlp It is understood that AFTER having considered $n=1$, the rest of the proof is for $n>1$ anyway I edited my proof so please delete your downvote

Comment: Not necessarily. Your (pre-edit) induction hypothesis __assumes__ $n=1$ to prove that it holds for $n=2$, however in your example this proof fails. In the very first step you very much have $n = 1$, because you use $n$ to prove $n+1$. If your proof instead uses $n-1$ to prove $n$, then you can start from $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you have $4^{n+1}>4n^2$ (from the induction hypothesis) you can try and prove that
$$
4n^2\ge(n+1)^2
$$

This is equivalent to
$$
3n^2-2n-1\ge0
$$
or $(3n+1)(n-1)\ge0$. Is this true?

Comment: It is true for $n\geq1$, and we already know that it is because we have begun the proof with $n=1$ and moved forward. (Is that right?) Thank you ::))

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın Yes: we are assuming $n\ge1$.