# Proof $4^n>n^2$

Tags: induction

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

Proof by mathematical induction:

$4^n>n^2$

I tried this:

$1.n=1\\4>1\\2.n=k\\4^k>k^2\\3.n=k+1\\4^{k+1}>(k+1)^2\\3k^2>2k+1$

And now, i don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is that even true? $n=-1\Rightarrow 4^{-1}=0.25, (-1)^2=1$

Comment: $4^n > n^2 \iff \sqrt{4^n} = 2^n > n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $4^n&gt;n^2$ using induction...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473163/how-to-prove-that-4nn2-using-induction)

Answer (score 1):

If $n=1$, it is clear that $4^n>n^2$.

Now, take $n\in\Bbb N$ and suppose that $4^n>n^2$. Then\begin{align}4^{n+1}&=4\times4^n\\&>4n^2\\&\geqslant(n+1)^2,\end{align}since$$\frac{n+1}n\leqslant2\implies\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\leqslant4.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$4^{k+1}=4 \cdot 4^k \stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}\ge 4 \cdot k^2\stackrel{?}\ge k^2+2k +1=(k+1)^2$$

and the inequality holds indeed

$$4 \cdot k^2\ge k^2+2k +1 \iff 3k^2-2k-1=(k-1)(3k+1)\ge 0$$

which is equivalent to your last inequality and true as $k\ge 1$.